# ledmac/-par: No versesyncing but pagesyncing

Tags: xetex, parallel, ledmac

I tried t get an answer at de.comp.text.tex, comp.text.tex [2] and golatex.de [1, in german] but 
without success. I hope to find help here.

My friend needs to typeset a translation of a latin poem with critical 
notes so we (I) decide to use ledmac an ledpar. The verses should be 
synced pagewise but not versewise, which means that there shouldn’t be 
any extra vertical space between to verses.

I try to show it in “ASCI-Art”:
This is how it should look like:

```
% left/even page (original)                right/odd page (translation) 
+-------------------------------------+    +-----------------------------------+ 
|  1 Lorem ipsum                      |    | 1 Dies ist die Übersetzung        | 
|  2 dolor sit amet, consectetuer     |    |     der ersten Zeile              | 
|  3 adipiscing elit. Aenean          |    | 2 und die zweite folgt            | 
|      commodo ligula eget dolor.     |    | 3 so wie die dritte, deren        | 
|      Aenean massa.                  |    |     Übersetzung wieder            | 
|  4 Cum sociis natoque penatibus     |    |     deutlich länger ist           | 
|  5 et magnis dis parturient montes, |    |     als das Original              | 
|  6 nascetur ridiculus mus.          |    | 4 kurze Übersetzung               | 
|  7 Donec quam felis, ultricies      |    | 5 ebenfalls kurz                  | 
|      nec, pellentesque eu,          |    | 6 und die Übersetzung der         | 
|      pretium quis, sem.             |    |    sechsten wieder etwas länger   | 
|                                     |    | 7 und die letzte Zeile bekommt    | 
|                                     |    |    noch eine besonders lange      | 
|                                     |    |    Übersetzung, um es wirklich    | 
|                                     |    |    deutlich zu machen.            | 
+-------------------------------------+    +-----------------------------------+
```

and this how it looks at the moment

```
% left/even page (original)                right/odd page (translation) 
+-------------------------------------+    +-----------------------------------+ 
|  1 Lorem ipsum                      |    | 1 Dies ist die Übersetzung        | 
|                                     |    |    der ersten Zeile               | 
|  2 dolor sit amet, consectetuer     |    | 2 und die zweite folgt            | 
|  3 adipiscing elit. Aenean          |    | 3 so wie die dritte, deren        | 
|      commodo ligula eget dolor.     |    |    Übersetzung wieder             | 
|      Aenean massa.                  |    |    deutlich länger ist            | 
|                                     |    |    als das Original               | 
|  4 Cum sociis natoque penatibus     |    | 4 kurze Übersetzung               | 
|  5 et magnis dis parturient montes, |    | 5 ebenfalls kurz                  | 
|  6 nascetur ridiculus mus.          |    | 6 und die Übersetzung der         | 
|                                     |    |    sechsten wieder etwas länger   | 
|  7 Donec quam felis, ultricies      |    | 7 und die letzte Zeile bekommt    | 
|      nec, pellentesque eu,          |    |    noch eine besonders lange      | 
|      pretium quis, sem.             |    |    Übersetzung, um es wirklich    | 
|                                     |    |    deutlich zu machen.            | 
+-------------------------------------+    +-----------------------------------+
```

Here is the—more or less—minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,DIV=7]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{xltxtra} 
\usepackage{ledmac,ledpar} 
\maxchunks{500} 
% Dummy 
\newcommand{\BNote}[2]{#1} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{pages} 
\begin{Leftside} 
    \beginnumbering% line numbers 
    \setstanzaindents{2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}% indents 
    \stanza 
    Non ego Caesareas \BNote{acies}{Anmerkung zum Text}, non arma virumque, & 
    sed chitaram plectrumque cano nec inutile numen & 
    totque etiam voces. \BNote{Quis}{Noch eine Anmerkung zum Text} enim laudare horaem & 
    et lyricam poterit, nisi centum vocibus, artem? 
            et lyricam poterit, nisi centum vocibus, artem? 
            et lyricam poterit, nisi centum vocibus, artem? 
    \& 
    \stanza 
    Doctus in Arcadiis vivebat musicus oris, & 
    clarus circa urbes et famae voce lyraeque. & 
    Illum laetus Hymen \BNote{et}{Foo} plausu iuvenumque choreis & 
    vicina quondam late celebratus in urbe 
    \& 
    \stanza 
    Doctus in Arcadiis vivebat musicus oris, & 
    clarus circa urbes et famae voce lyraeque. & 
    Illum laetus Hymen et plausu iuvenumque choreis & 
    vicina quondam late celebratus in urbe 
    \& 
    \stanza 
    Doctus in Arcadiis vivebat musicus oris, & 
    clarus circa urbes et famae voce lyraeque. & 
    Illum laetus Hymen et plausu iuvenumque choreis & 
    vicina quondam late celebratus in urbe 
    \& 
    \stanza 
    Doctus in Arcadiis vivebat musicus oris, & 
    clarus circa urbes et famae voce lyraeque. & 
    Illum laetus Hymen et plausu iuvenumque choreis & 
    vicina quondam late celebratus in urbe 
    \& 
    \endnumbering 
\end{Leftside} 
\begin{Rightside} 
    \beginnumbering
    \setstanzaindents{2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    \stanza 
    Nicht singe ich von Cäsars Heer, nicht von Waffen und einem Helden, & 
    sondern von Cithara und Plektrum und eine nicht unnützliche Gottheit 
            sondern von Cithara und Plektrum und eine nicht unnützliche Gottheit & 
    rufe ich zu Hilfe: Möge mich jener bekannte und lebendige Anhelitus/ Odem, & 
    der gewöhnlich durch die klangvolle Tibia bläst, mit reichem 
    \& 
    \stanza 
    Jenen zog der fröhliche Hymen, der mit Klatschen und Reigentänzen junger Männer 
            Jenen zog der fröhliche Hymen, der mit Klatschen und Reigentänzen 
            junger Männer& 
    einst in einer benachbarten Stadt ausgiebig gefeiert wurde, & 
    zusammen mit anderen lyrischen Sängern zu der so großen Festlichkeit & 
    durch die Aussicht auf Lohn und Speise, damit er der Sitte nach 
    \& 
    \stanza 
    Jenen zog der fröhliche Hymen, der mit Klatschen und Reigentänzen junger Männer & 
    einst in einer benachbarten Stadt ausgiebig gefeiert wurde, & 
    zusammen mit anderen lyrischen Sängern zu der so großen Festlichkeit & 
    durch die Aussicht auf Lohn und Speise, damit er der Sitte nach 
    \& 
    \stanza 
    Jenen zog der fröhliche Hymen, der mit Klatschen und Reigentänzen junger Männer & 
    einst in einer benachbarten Stadt ausgiebig gefeiert wurde, & 
    zusammen mit anderen lyrischen Sängern zu der so großen Festlichkeit & 
    durch die Aussicht auf Lohn und Speise, damit er der Sitte nach 
    \& 
    \stanza 
    Jenen zog der fröhliche Hymen, der mit Klatschen und Reigentänzen junger Männer & 
    einst in einer benachbarten Stadt ausgiebig gefeiert wurde, & 
    zusammen mit anderen lyrischen Sängern zu der so großen Festlichkeit & 
    durch die Aussicht auf Lohn und Speise, damit er der Sitte nach 
    \& 
    \endnumbering 
\end{Rightside} 
\Pages 
\end{pages} 
\end{document}
```

We use XeLaTeX to get the PDF.

Thank’s for every help!
Tobi

ps: I’m sorry for my bad english, but hope you understand … O:-)
pps: Does anybody know who the maintainer is, cause Peter Wilson stopped developing in 2008 (seen on CTAN)?

[1] http://www.golatex.de/ledmac-par-ein-paar-fragen-u-a-zum-parallelen-text-t6280.html
[2] http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_frm/thread/39f94ec919c4c91a

Comment: The maintainer (Vafa Khalighi) is mentioned in the CTAN catalog entry http://ctan.org/pkg/ledmac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a quick and dirty hack:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Pages}{\hb@xt@ \hsize{\ledstrutL\unhbox\l@dleftbox}}{\ifdim\ht\l@dleftbox>0pt\hb@xt@ \hsize{\ledstrutL\unhbox\l@dleftbox}\fi}{}{}
\patchcmd{\Pages}{\hb@xt@ \hsize{\ledstrutR\unhbox\l@drightbox}}{\ifdim\ht\l@drightbox>0pt\hb@xt@ \hsize{\ledstrutR\unhbox\l@drightbox}\fi}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Insert this code after you have loaded [`ledmac`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ledmac) and [`ledpar`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ledpar). It redefines the central output routine so that the height of the box to be inserted is checked. If it is zero, the box is omitted. This prevents blank lines used to synchronize the verses, but it may have potential drawbacks I'm not aware of.

You may also want to increase the amount of the page used by the parallel text:

```
\renewcommand*{\goalfraction}{0.95}
```

Comment: Note: If I compile the document with this adaption, it gives a compiling error at first, which vanishes after a few LaTeX runs. The output file gives the desired result.

Comment: That seems to work fine. Thank you very much! Do you know if there’s a way to force a pagebreak? Cause if I compile my example-file with your hack and without changing `\goalfraction`, it leads do a pagebreak between line 10R an it’s continuation (p. 3 to 5 at the resulting PDF).

Comment: @Tobi Unfortunately, I don't know an easy way to force a page break - the only thing I can think of is to end the `Leftside`/`Rightside`/`\Pages` construct and to start a new one. It seems to be a general problem of `ledpar`, however, that verses can be broken between pages. Maybe you should post a new question asking how to avoid this behaviour.

Comment: This could be a workaround thank you for this idea!