# ledpar: How to force a pagebreak in {pages}-environment/stanzas?

Tags: page-breaking, ledmac, parallel

How can I force a pagebreak in `ledpar`’s `{pages}`-environment between to `\stanza`s or even between two lines of a single `\stanza`? The reason for my question is that `ledpar` sometimes breaks the page between a verse an it’s continuation in the next line, e.g.

**This is a verse is to long to fit in**
— `ledpar` inserts a pagebreak here —
(indent) **a single line**

That’s not good to read an I want to force a pagebreak before “This is …”

In a comment at “[ledmac/-par: No versesyncing but pagesyncing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15889/ledmac-par-no-versesyncing-but-pagesyncing/15905#15905)” diabonas suggests to stop the `left`-/`rightpage`/`\Pages`-construc manually to force a pagebreak but I hope there’s a more elegant way …?

This is a minimal example for testing. I’ve tried three versions; related code is marked with [*n*].

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}% very small pages to see an effect
\geometry{paperheight=4cm,paperwidth=6cm,vmargin=1cm}
\usepackage{ledmac,ledpar}

\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
    \setstanzaindents{2,0,0,0}
    \stanza 1 & 2 & 3 \&
    \stanza 4 & 5 & 6 \&
%   \stanza\pagebreak\&% [1] doesn't work
%   \pagebreak% [2,3] doesn't work too
    \stanza 7 & 8 & 9 \&
    \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \setstanzaindents{2,0,0,0}
    \stanza one & two & three \&
    \stanza four & five & six \&
%   \stanza\pagebreak\&% [1] doesn't work
%   \pagebreak% [3] doesn't work too
    \stanza seven & eight & nine \&
    \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
    \Pages
\end{pages}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution is certainly no "more elegant way" in terms of beautiful coding - it's the exact opposite indeed! - but it seems to work:

### Code:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\pageisfull}{\def\checkpageL{\l@dpagefulltrue\l@dsamepagefalse}}
\newcommand*{\fakelineL}{{\ledRcolfalse\new@line\startlock\skipnumbering\endlock\null}}
\newcommand*{\fakelineR}{{\ledRcoltrue\new@lineR\startlock\skipnumbering\endlock\null}}
\patchcmd{\Pages}{\hb@xt@ \hsize{\ledstrutL\unhbox\l@dleftbox}}{\ifdim\dp\l@dleftbox=12mm\pageisfull\fakelineL\else\hb@xt@ \hsize{\ledstrutL\unhbox\l@dleftbox}\fi}{}{}
\patchcmd{\Pages}{\hb@xt@ \hsize{\ledstrutR\unhbox\l@drightbox}}{\ifdim\dp\l@drightbox=12mm\fakelineR\else\hb@xt@ \hsize{\ledstrutR\unhbox\l@drightbox}\fi}{}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\ledparpagebreak}{\stanza\strut\vrule depth12mm\&}
```

### Explanation:

The central output routine `\Pages` is modified in order to check wether the box to be inserted has a depth of `12mm`. This is rather unrealistic for normal boxes, so it will serve as a marker for a page break at this point. If such a special box is found, it isn't output - instead, the newly defined macros `\fakelineL`/`\fakelineR` and `\pageisfull` are executed:

The `\fakeline.` commands behave if there really was a line to be inserted, but they execute the necessary macros to *skip* the number for this line. This may sound weird, but it proves to be necessary to (hopefully) get correct line numbers.

The macro `\pageisfull` hacks `\checkboxL` which controls if a page break is needed so that it forces a new page. (This redefinition is local because it is inside a group in `\Pages`, so we don't have to reset the  change as this is done automatically at the end of the group.)

Now we just have to define a macro `\ledparpagebreak` which inserts such a box of depth `12mm` to be able to control the page breaking: It starts a new stanza (otherwise, the output routine can't handle it correctly) with a `\vrule` set to the desired depth.

### Usage:

Just add the code to your LaTeX document after you have loaded `ledpar`. You can then use `\ledparpagebreak` between two stanzas to insert a page break at this point. Make sure to use the command in *both* columns (after corresponding stanzas, otherwise you may observe weird behaviour...).

You can use this hack parallel to the patch suggested in the answer to [your related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15889/ledmac-par-no-versesyncing-but-pagesyncing) as both should be compatible.

### WARNING:

As I said, this is no clean approach *at all*, I can't guarantee correct behaviour, especially regarding consistent line numbering, in all cases (it worked properly with my test texts, though).

It may be a better idea to take advantage of the so-called "action-code list" `ledmac` introduces: It seems to me that it is specially made in order to do special tasks at certain lines, like starting a new page. However, I do not understand the internals of `ledmac`/`ledpar` well enough to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much (especial for explaining your code in detail)! I’ll try it when finally typesetting the document and report about—hopefully—success or not …

Comment: ps. Did you only read the manual to get this idea/solution or are there any further informations the I’ve overlooked?

Comment: Hy, the translation is finished now and I tried your soulution but it causes some strange errors (e. g. print all verse nums in footnotes as 0) that I don’t comprehend. The other solution I found is to put an invisible rule in the line before the break to make it long enough to fill the page (I set the rule via `\newcommand{\ledstrut}[1]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{#1}}`). That works for me and don’t causes problems—at least as far as I can see … Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @diabonas : I just tried your solution without stanza in my document and it seems to work. However, the linecounter seems to miss a line: `... - 73 - 74 - pagebreak - 76 - 77 - ...`. Pther than that, I really like your solution!