# pagebreak in ledpar (eledpar)

Tags: page-breaking, luatex, ledmac

I am sort of restating [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16188/12277) -- however only sort of.

I will (1) describe a problem, (2) assume something about the functions of `ledpar`, and (3) ask a question.

## 1. Problem

I am typesetting a bilingual edition of a text: edition on the left, translation on the right page. Since the translation is much longer than the original, the pagesynchronization is rarely correct (I assume that the unequal lengths of text on both pages is at least in part responsible; this assumption could be wrong, of course).

Anyway, I would like to be able to insert a pagebreak manually an thereby to synchronize the contents manually. AFAIK such a manual pagebreak is not implemented in `ledpar`. There is [this fine solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16188/12277), but I want to state the problem from a slightly different angle.

## 2. Assumption

I guess `ledpar` works like this:

- looking at the text on both sides,
- trying measure the contents on both sides,
- deciding for a portion of text on the left page,
- **using some sort of command in order to let the left page break** after that portion,
- trying to measure the corresponding text on the right page,
- trying to determine an equal portion on the right page and the correct spot for the break,
- **using some sort of command in order to let the right page break**,
- go to the next portion of text... etc.

## 3. Question

What is this **command that lets the page break**? This command -- or something like it -- must exist, because `ledpar` uses it itself automatically all the time, right? So, can I just manually use this very same **command that lets the page break** myself wherever I want? If this command is some bigger function, then I think it should be possible to `define` a command I could execute in my text.

Comment: This is probabably the same problem/request as [here on github](https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/6). There doesn't seem to be a solution for this right now, but Maïeul put it on the to-do list for a later release. But if you can find a solution right now: By all means do so! It's a big problem for me, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version 1.5.0 of eledpar add tools to manage pagebreak on eledpar. There is two commands : `\ledpb` to make page break, and `\lednopb` to prevent page break, by adding new line. It needs to make two runs.

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment than as an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It's an answer: the author ask to a problem. I say this problem is solved in a new version of package...

Comment: I have completed my answer.

Comment: Now it looks like an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is an answer or not. I originally wrote `ledpar` way back when but now looking at the code I don't really know how it works. Also, it has now been overtaken by a non-upward compatible descendent called `eledpar` (similarly `eledmac`).

However, there are a couple of macros that just might do what you want (but more likely they won't; I haven't tried). In your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\clearledleftpage\clearl@dleftpage
\let\clearledrightpage\clearl@drightpage
\makeatother
```

and then try using `\clearled...page` when you want to clear the left/right page.

Another possible solution is to use different textwidths for the left and right pages; narrow for the shorter text and wider for the longer text. The lengths `\Lcolwidth` and `\Rcolwidth` are the textwidths for the left and right pages, respectively. They can be changed within the `pages` environment.

Comment: that sounded promising, it doesn't work, though. I added on both sides a `\clearled...page` between `\pstart` and `\pend` with no other effect than (1) `the x page ended on a y page` and (2) adding to empty pages. Thanks for the great package, nevertheless!

Comment: @Peter Wilson : the problem is that the command \clearledleftpage in interpreted before the \Pages command is called. So it could'nt work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you, but just in case.

Yo can always start a new page manually with tre command \pages

This will start a new series of parallel chunks.

I also have used

\global\def\goalfraction{n}

Where n is a number between 0 and 1 (normally something like 0.90) and sets the fraction of the page length taht your texts are using. It is tricky to use and I dont think it is a clean solution, but i managed to fix some ugly white  spaces with it.