# distribute contents of two input-files to left and right pages

Tags: page-breaking, input, include, book-design

Is it possible to import two tex files with `\input` and to have the content of the one file be always on the left page *facing* the content of the other file being always on the right? The page numbers should go on continuously 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

(Actually I guess that this is not so easy to be achieved.)

I imagine something like this:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}

\input[left]{file_A.tex}
\input[right]{file_B.tex}

\end{document}
```

Both files would just consist of simple data such as

```
\chapter{Chapter}
Text.
\section{Section}
Text. ...
```

Nonetheless both files will be long and contain several pages worth of text. In other words, I would have two long files `file_A.tex` and `file_B.tex` and latex fills me the left page consecutively with the contents of A and the right pages consecutively with the contents of B.

This being said, I don't mind (and in fact would prefer!) to cut the contents of the two files in page-size chunks by manually using `\pagebreak` several times at appropriate places within each file.

Comment: I guess you could typeset them both on their own and increment the page counter by 2 on each page, then splice the pdfs together?

Comment: Yes, I thought of this. This is one -- potentially laborious -- way to do it.

Comment: why not using eledpar?

Comment: actually, because I am looking for an alternative to `eledmac`/`eledpar`, as I have been unable to overcome my problems with these packages for three years.

Comment: what are the problems?

Comment: @Maïeul We have been in contact about some of these a few months back, if you remember. Especially the way how `eledpar` creates page breaks automatically is unsatisfying in my case, i.e., the text on the left is not synchronised with the text on the right. It's just not good enough to be published that way, although some features of `eledpar` are just really cool. Since `eledpar` automatises many thinks (e.g., page breaks and so on ) and does not allow the user to intervene, I am now looking for a less automatic and more hands-on approach - even if that is at the expense of the cool features.

Comment: eledpar has now a manual page break system.

Comment: @Maïeul do you mean `\ledpb`? I tried it but could not make it work. I'd be glad if you could show me here in an answer how I can use `eledpar` with manual page breaks on both pages. just a quick minimal example would suffice. you could also do it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147018/12277

Comment: I should need some example in which \ledpb doesn't worrk to understand. All my test with \ledpb were working.

Comment: @Maïeul maybe it would then help if you showed as an answer to this questions how \ledpb works

Comment: it's work like explained in this handbook. See this MWE http://pastebin.fr/38373

Comment: @Maïeul : ok I see this works for Latin text. Thx. Still I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: non only latin text...

Answer (score 1):

You can probably arrange to store each page in a box instead of shipping it out, and then sorting the boxes at the end, something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}

\newcount\zzz
\newif\ifdone
\let\zzshipout\shipout
\makeatletter
\def\shipout\vbox#1{%
\edef\x{\noexpand\typeout{page \thepage\space is box \the\zzz}}\x
\global\setbox\zzz\vbox{#1}%
\global\advance\zzz1 %
\stepcounter{page}%
}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\zzz=5001\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{file_A.tex}

\clearpage
\zzz=6001\setcounter{page}{2}
\input{file_B.tex}
\clearpage

\typeout{===========}

\makeatletter
\begingroup 
  \let \protect \noexpand
  \@resetactivechars
  \@parboxrestore
 \global\c@page=1
\loop
\ifvoid\numexpr5000+\c@page\relax
  \ifvoid\numexpr6000+\c@page\relax
    \donetrue
  \else
    \zzshipout\vbox{\hbox{blank A}}%
    \zzshipout\box\numexpr6000+\c@page
  \fi
\else
  \zzshipout\box\numexpr5000+\c@page
  \ifvoid\numexpr6000+\c@page\relax
    \zzshipout\vbox{\hbox{blank B}}%
  \else
    \zzshipout\box\numexpr6000+\c@page
  \fi
\fi
\ifdone\else
\global\advance\c@page1 %
\repeat

\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry acrobat has done the usual thing and shown the spreads reversed with odd side to the left.