# ledpar: Get rid of any space between paragraphs while retaining the synchronization of the pagecontents

Tags: luatex, fontspec, ledmac, parallel, arabic

My question: Is there a way to simply get rid of any space between the paragraphs of `ledpar`- while retaining the pagesynch? (I understand that synchronizing paragraphs is a feature of ledpar, put I think it should be a feature which the user could turn off...)

I have a problem (similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15889/)) with an edition of an Arabic text with a translation on the facing page. The paragraphs are only synchronized if I force the Arabic font to be exactly as high as the latin font (using fontspec `Scale=MatchUppercase`; I use LuaLaTeX and KOMA). However, the Arabic text is then really too small and fairly unreadable. If I increase the size of the Arabic script (e.g. by declaring that the Arabic text is `\Large`), the paragraphs are no longer synchronized.

Then I decided to get rid of the synchronization of paragraphs (because in research literature, paragraphs are rarely - if at all - synchronized the way ledpar does it).
I found diabonas' quick hack [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15905/12277). But don't get it to work. (Maybe it is because this hack is for `ledpar` with `stanza`)

(Perhaps not so minimal) working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Numbers=Arabic, Scale=MatchLowercase]{Scheherazade}

\usepackage{ledmac, ledpar}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}        %% This was diabonas' solution to the question I was referring to. (see link above)
%\makeatletter
%\patchcmd{\Pages}{\hb@xt@ \hsize{\ledstrutL\unhbox\l@dleftbox}}{\ifdim\ht\l@dleftbox>0pt\hb@xt@ \hsize{\ledstrutL\unhbox\l@dleftbox}\fi}{}{}
%\patchcmd{\Pages}{\hb@xt@ \hsize{\ledstrutR\unhbox\l@drightbox}}{\ifdim\ht\l@drightbox>0pt\hb@xt@ \hsize{\ledstrutR\unhbox\l@drightbox}\fi}{}{}
%\makeatother

\newcommand{\arabtxt}[1] % Arabic inside LTR
    {\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}
\newenvironment{arabpar}     % Arabic paragraph
    {\luatextextdir TRT\luatexpardir TRT\arabicfont}{}

\newcommand{\arabnormaltext}
    {\Large}

%\shiftedversestrue     % This is the solution to my problem as suggested by the package maintainer

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
Text.

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\linenummargin{outer}
\sidenotemargin{inner}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{arabpar}
\section*{Second Part}
\arabnormaltext\noindent\setline{1}%
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين ١٢٣٤٥ فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين حاشية عربية. فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين. فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين ١٢٣٤٥ فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين حاشية عربية. فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين.
\hfill\end{arabpar}
\pend
\pstart\begin{arabpar}\arabnormaltext
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين ١٢٣٤٥ فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين حاشية عربية. فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين. فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين ١٢٣٤٥ فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين حاشية عربية. فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين. فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين ١٢٣٤٥ فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين حاشية عربية. فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين.
\hfill\end{arabpar}
\pend
\pstart\begin{arabpar}\arabnormaltext
فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين ١٢٣٤٥ فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين حاشية عربية. فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين. فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين ١٢٣٤٥ فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين فقرة عربية محاذاة إلى اليمين حاشية عربية.
\hfill\end{arabpar}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\linenummargin{outer}
\sidenotemargin{outer}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\section{Second Part}
\noindent\setline{1}%
English text. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned. English text. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned. English text. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned.
\pend
\pstart
English text. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned. English text. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned. English text. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned. English text. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned. English text. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned. English text. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned.
\pend
\pstart
English text. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned. English text. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned. English text. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned. English text. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned. English text. English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned English paragraph left aligned.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\Pages
\end{pages}
\end{document}
```

So, it seems that the synchronization goes down the drain because of the different fontsizes. Can't we just get rid of the space between the paragraphs (and hope that the pagecontents will still be somehow synchronized)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I removed the thanks. There's no need to add a thanks to your question. Thanks is best expressed in the upvoting of helpful answers.

Comment: At the moment, I am not even able to get diabolas' quick hack to work. This morning it did work as I described. But now, it doesn't... Don't ask me why.
But the question remains: who to remove the space between paragraphs in ledpar.

Do you still need a minimal working example? how do I add it here when only 500 characters are allowed?

Comment: @Tobi
It does not even work, when I use the example you've posted in the question I was referring to.

Comment: @ClintEastwood: You should add the MWE to your question (by clicking “edit”) not as comment. Even if there is an example in an other question, it is preferred to have one for each question on it’s own. Furthermore you use LuaTeX and Arabic text which is not part of my example. I suggest to adapt my example an add it here. If my example doesn’t compile as it is on your machine it is maybe broken by an `ledpar` update. In this cas you may add a comment there …

Comment: @ClintEastwood: I can’t answer your question, but thanks for your MWE. Until I tried compiling it, I had never managed to get bidi working in LuaTeX.

Comment: @Tobi: I did modify my question and formulated it more precisely. Furthermore, I contacted the package maintainer and he said that what I asked for is possible only with stanza. For the normal paragraph I should create a ticket on github and he'll see what he can do. In any case he won't and can't do anything about it before summer. But he was surprised that that the second question could not be solved using `setspace`.

Comment: Clint, This does not exactly answer your question, but could put you on the way of other solutions, if you cannot fix your problem with ledpar. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/878/how-do-i-create-parallel-text-aligned-by-paragraph?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted the current package maintainer (Maïeul Rouquette) a few months ago and posted my problem on his github-page. Now, he came up with a solution (thanks for that!).

The space between paragraphs can be removed by adding `\shiftedversestrue` to the preamble. Originally this command was designed for the stanza environment of the ledmac package, but it works also for non-stanza. (I adjusted the above MWE)

However, in my case this now adds another problem: I now need to find a way to add the page-breaks manually as the texts do absolutely not run parallel anymore. But I'll post this question another day.

Anyway, the question I asked 6 months ago seems to be solved.